# React Final Form wizard losing registered fields when passing subscription prop

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I'm having a bit of a strange issue with React Final Form. I'm using the wizard pattern from the documentation. If I pass a `subscription` to the form, only the fields from the previous step appear as registered. If I don't pass a `subscription` then all the fields for all steps are registered, which is what I want.

```
const subscription = { submitError: true, submitting: true}

render() {
    return (
        <Form subscription={subscription} {...my other form props} />
```

Do I need to subscribe to another state in order to get all my registered fields back?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. Upon further inspection, the step was not actually loading with the fields registered, but was rendering twice and they were registered on the second render. Adding `touched: true` to my subscriptions fixed this for me. Not quite sure why yet.